# current_page helper methods returns "No routes match" error in some controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a decorate method like this.

```
class ShortPositionDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all
  def foo
     return unelss h.current_page?(action: 'seller', controller: 'short_positions')
     'OK'
  end
end
```

When I open a page `/short_positions/1`, then there is no error and `OK` is shown.

But when I open `/users/positions` it ends up with a error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"seller", :controller=>"short_positions"}
```

How can I avoid the error?

#### config/routes.rb

I have these two config in `routes.rb`.

```
get '/short_positions/:id', to: 'short_positions#seller', as: :seller
get '/users/positions', to: 'users#positions', as: :user_positions
```

Comment: As far I can see you are trying to use a nested route with `/users/positions`. Do you have correctly declare this route in your `route.rb` file ? It will be better if you could update your question with the content of this file.

Comment: I added the `routes.rb`, so this is not a nested route. Maybe I should use a nested route, though.